# Math expression evaluator

Tags: c++, performance, parsing, math-expression-eval

It is my second attempt to make a math expression evaluator.

To evaluate an expression, I created a class that works like this:

-it removes all the blank spaces

-if brackets are present, it processes them by creating another evaluator with the expression inside those brackets

-it gets all the numbers and does first all the exponentiations, then the multiplications/divisions and finally sums all the numbers

For example, let's say I have the expression $$3*(3+4)^2+3*(5+6)$$

-replaces (3+4) and (5+6) with 7 and 11  $$3*7^2+3*11$$

-does 7^2 $$3*49+3*11$$

-does the multiplications $$147+33$$

-sums all the numbers $$180$$

If you know if there's something wrong or to optimize I'd really appreciate it

**MathSolver.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

void changeCharacters(std::string chars, std::string toChange, std::string &str)
{
    int i = -1;
    std::for_each(str.begin(), str.end(), [chars, toChange, &i, &str](char c)
    {
        i++;
        for (auto &j : chars)
        {
            if (c == j)
            {
                str.erase(str.begin() + i);
                str.insert(i, toChange);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}

class MathSolver
{
private:
    std::string exp;
    std::vector<double> nums;
    double result;
    std::function<bool(char)> isPlusMinus = [](char c) {return c == '+' || c == '-'; };
    std::function<bool(char)> isMultDiv = [](char c) {return c == '*' || c == '/'; };

public:
    MathSolver(std::string exp)
    {
        exp.erase(std::remove(exp.begin(), exp.end(), ' '), exp.end());
        if (exp.find_first_of("+-") != 0)
            exp.insert(0, "+");
        for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++)
        {
            if (isPlusMinus(exp[i]))
                exp.insert(i + 1, "1*");
        }
        changeCharacters("[{", "(", exp);
        changeCharacters("]}", ")", exp);
        changeCharacters(":", "/", exp);
        this->exp = exp;
        this->processBrackets();
        this->parse();
    }
    void countBracks(std::vector< std::pair<int, int>> &bracks)
    {
        int parOC = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++)
        {
            if (exp[i] == '(')
            {
                if (parOC == 0)
                    bracks.push_back(std::make_pair(i, 0));
                parOC++;
            }
            else if (exp[i] == ')')
            {
                parOC--;
                if (parOC == 0)
                    bracks[bracks.size() - 1].second = i;
            }
        }
    }
    void processBrackets()
    {
        std::vector< std::pair<int, int>> bracks;
        countBracks(bracks);
        int count = bracks.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            std::pair<int, int> j = bracks[0];
            MathSolver solve(exp.substr(j.first + 1, j.second - 1 - j.first));
            double res = solve.getResult();
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << res;
            exp.erase(exp.begin() + j.first, exp.begin() + j.second + 1);
            exp.insert(j.first, ss.str());

            bracks.clear();
            countBracks(bracks);
        }
    }
    void parse()
    {
        std::function<void(double&, std::istringstream&)> searchPow = [](double &num, std::istringstream &iss)
        {
            if (iss.peek() == '^')
            {
                char tmp2;
                double tmp3;
                iss >> tmp2 >> tmp3;
                num = pow(num, tmp3);

            }
        };
        double num;
        char tmp;
        std::istringstream iss(exp);
        while ((int)iss.tellg() != EOF)
        {
            if (isPlusMinus(iss.peek()) && isdigit(exp[(int)iss.tellg() + 1]))
            {
                iss >> num;
                searchPow(num, iss);
                nums.push_back(num);
            }
            else if (isMultDiv(iss.peek()) && (isdigit(exp[(int)iss.tellg() + 1]) || isdigit(exp[(int)iss.tellg() + 2])))
            {
                iss >> tmp >> num;
                searchPow(num, iss);
                nums.push_back(num);

                if (tmp == '/')
                    nums[nums.size() - 1] = 1 / nums[nums.size() - 1];
                nums[nums.size() - 1] *= nums[nums.size() - 2];
                nums[nums.size() - 2] = 0;
            }
        }
        nums.erase(remove(nums.begin(), nums.end(), 0), nums.end());

        for (auto i : nums)
            result += i;
    }
    double getResult()
    {
        return result;
    }
};
```

Comment: There is an entire field in computer science dedicated to this, i. e. to formally describe the syntax of expressions or entire languages and to implement its parsing, execution and/or compilation. The usual approach is define the syntax, implement a tokenizer (splits string into the numbers and operators) and implement the parsing (checks syntax and immediately evaluate expression).  The easiest to understand parser is the [recursive descent parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).

Comment: You can also use the [shunting yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), which is specifically designed for such math expressions. It might be easier to build a fully fledged parser :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are some thoughts about your already quite nice code:

1. use `std::isspace` for whitespace detection. In that case you can do

   `str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isspace), str.end());`
2. Don't use unnecessary abbreviations: bracks vs brackets is not really a gain at all.
3. You should use a `std::stack` for bracket checking. So whenever you encounter an opening bracket you put it on the stack and check the next one.
4. You might want to get a separate function for extraction of the inner bracket content such like this:

   ```
   std:string innerBracketString(const std::string& expr, 
                                 size_t& startPos, 
                                 size_t& endPos) {
       startPos = expr.find_first_of("([{", endPos)+1;
       endPos   = expr.find_first_of(")]}", startPos);
       return expr.substr(startPos, endPos - startPos);
   }
   ```